# SharePoint User Profiles not sync with AD

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have the problem with recent added Office365 users that there are **not** synchronised with *SharePoint Online* user profiles.

When I try to add the user manually, there can't get found here:

[image]

I have no idea, what can do against this state of Office365. Is there any SPO PowerShell commands I could slam here?

Answer (score 1):

In this type of scenario we need to verify couple of things. From SharePoint online admin center navigate to **user profile** service, there try to find that user, if it is found there in the user profile directory, then there is no issue with the sync.

For details steps how to navigate to user profile in SharePoint online admin center, please refer the below article :

[Manage user profiles in the SharePoint admin center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint/manage-user-profiles?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fManage-SharePoint-Online-user-profiles-from-the-SharePoint-admin-center-494bec9c-6654-41f0-920f-f7f937ea9723)

Second thing to look upon, add the problematic user directly to the **user information** list (SharePoint hidden list) and try to access the SharePoint site, at this point mostly user will not be able access the site, will get access denied error.  Now, wait for few hours to run the synchronization job to run, in the next run it should be synchronized.

**Note** :

- For all types of licenses, user profile service doesn't synchronize automatically in SharePoint online, in those scenarios, need synchronize manually.
- Adding user using PowerShell is more effective than the from the UI in terms of synchronization.

Similar question is discussed in the below thread :

- [Users are in Office 365 but do not yet have a user profile SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219201/users-are-in-office-365-but-do-not-yet-have-a-user-profile-sharepoint-online)

Comment: @HaliburRahaman, thanks for your reply. To your first aspect: no, the user is not a member of the user profile. And to your second part: did I understand it correctly, that SPO creates a profile after the user make initial login to SharePoint? How can I manually trigger a synchronisation?

Comment: Try to add the user in user information hidden list using PnP PowerShell or PowerShell, then try to access the site using that user,at this moment user cannot access it. Wait for few hours sometime it takes 24 hours to synchronization to happen in SPO.

Comment: Never heard of the _hidden list_ thanks for that information!